# How to rotate an image about the Z Axis in JOGL without using the glRotateF built-in functions

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

How can I rotate an image about the Z axis in JOGL without using `glRotatef` function? I don't understand how to get **z'** since there is no `e.getZ()` function. How might one calculate a `z_prime`? Right now when I try to rotate about the z axis, it like rotates it about the z axis in the beggining and then begins rotating it about the y axis and then back to the z (which makes sense because i have `z_rot += y_prime`. How can I just rotate it about the **z** and calculate a **z'**?

```
        public void transform(float[] vertices_in, float[] vertices_out){

            // perform your transformation

            int length = vertices_in.length;
            float[] transformMatrix = 
                {
                   r11, r12, r13, tx,
                   r21, r22, r23, ty,
                   r31, r32, r33, tz,
                   0,   0,   0, 1
                };




            // Fill in the empty verticesout vector
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices_in.length; i++)
            {
                vertices_out[i] = vertices_in[i];
            }
            // loop through and set the new matrix (after translation)
            // because
            // 1 0 0 0
            // 0 1 0 0
            // 0 0 1 0

            // X Rotation
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices_out.length; i += 3)
            {
                vertices_out[i+1] = vertices_out[i+1] * (float)Math.cos(xRot) - vertices_out[i+2] * (float)Math.sin(xRot); //New Y
                vertices_out[i+2] = vertices_out[i+1] * (float)Math.sin(xRot) + vertices_out[i+2] * (float)Math.cos(xRot); //New Z
            }

            // Y Rotation
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices_out.length; i += 3)
            {
                vertices_out[i] = vertices_out[i] * (float)Math.cos(yRot) + vertices_out[i+2] * (float)Math.sin(yRot);
                vertices_out[i+2] = vertices_out[i]*-(float)Math.sin(yRot) + vertices_out[i+2]*(float)Math.cos(yRot);
            }

            // Z Rotation
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices_out.length; i += 3)
            {
                vertices_out[i] = vertices_out[i] * (float)Math.cos(zRot) - vertices_out[i+1] * (float)Math.sin(zRot);
                vertices_out[i+1] = vertices_out[i] * (float)Math.sin(zRot) + vertices_out[i+1] * (float)Math.cos(zRot);
            }

            // Translation & Scaling
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices_in.length; i+=3)
            {
                vertices_out[i] = vertices_out[i] * transformMatrix[0] + transformMatrix[3]; //x'
                vertices_out[i+1] = vertices_out[i+1] * transformMatrix[5] + transformMatrix[7]; //y'
                vertices_out[i+2] = vertices_out[i+2] * transformMatrix[10] + transformMatrix[11]; //z'
            }

        }

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
        if(rotating)
        {
            float XX = (e.getX()-windowWidth*0.5f)*orthoX/windowWidth;
            float YY = -(e.getY()-windowHeight*0.5f)*orthoX/windowWidth;

            float x_prime = (StartXX - XX);
            float y_prime = (StartYY - YY);

            if(rightMouseClick)
            {
                zRot += y_prime/50;

            }
            else
            {
                xRot += y_prime/50;
                yRot += x_prime/50;
                StartYY = YY;
                StartXX = XX;   
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: What? Are you trying to implement a trackball?

Comment: No, I'm trying to rotate my image about the z axis. It just seems like I'm doing it wrong, the image looks like it is increasing about the z at first then it looks as if its increasing about the y, then z again - I just want it to rotate about the z axis, does that make sense? Or is that not possible @NicoSchertler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these rotations are using an inconsistent intermediate state. E.g (I just substituted for shorter variable names).

```
y = y * (float)Math.cos(xRot) - z * (float)Math.sin(xRot); //New Y
z = y * (float)Math.sin(xRot) + z * (float)Math.cos(xRot); //New Z
```

The first line is correct. However, the second line already uses the new `y` when it should use the old one. Hence, you have to save the old variable somewhere to make it work. The same applies to all other rotations.

The rest of the code looks ok.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank you